# ''EditItem' is not allowed for this view.' when trying to edit a item in the DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

So when I doubleclick an item to edit the value in my datagrid I keep getting the error message.

> ''EditItem' is not allowed for this view.'

And it looks like this
[image]

I've never encountered that before so I am not sure what way to go to deal with this.
What is causing this issue and what is the correct way of dealing with such an issue so I know how to deal with it in the future.
I tried looking into it on Google but it all had with lists to do and since I am not using a list I couldnt see the connection to my application.

XAML

```
    <DataGrid Name="dgItems">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Property" Binding="{Binding Property}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

CS

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string path = "";
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "Properties | *.properties";
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        path = ofd.FileName;
    }
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (!line.StartsWith("#"))
            {
                string[] lines = line.Split('=');
                string property = lines[0];
                string value = lines[1];
                this.dgItems.Items.Add(new ServerProperties { Property = property, Value = value });
                Debug.Print($"Property: {property} Value: {value}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Class that gets & sets the values

```
public class ServerProperties
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to a collection that implements the `IList` interface for you to be able to edit the items:

```
var list = new List<ServerProperties> { ... };
dgItems.ItemsSource = list;
```

Don't add any items directly to the `Items` property of the `DataGrid`:

```
dgItems.Items.Add(new ServerProperties());
```

So you should modify your code slightly:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string path = "";
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "Properties | *.properties";
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        path = ofd.FileName;
    }
    List<ServerProperties> serverProperties = new List<ServerProperties>();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (!line.StartsWith("#"))
            {
                string[] lines = line.Split('=');
                string property = lines[0];
                string value = lines[1];
                serverProperties.Add(new ServerProperties { Property = property, Value = value });
                Debug.Print($"Property: {property} Value: {value}");
            }
        }
    }
    dgItems.ItemsSource = serverProperties;
}
```

Comment: Oh so thats how datagrids work! You need to populate them with a list and then you can change that list! That makes sense!

Comment: But then there is the issue of saving the new value(s) Is there a event for when the item is changed that I can play around with?

Comment: When a property gets set to a new value, its setter is invoked. So you could whatever you want in there, for example raise an event.

Comment: _When a property gets set to a new value, its setter is invoked_ Do you mean that, everytime I change a value, it "Reloads" the ClickEvent?

Comment: No. When exactly do you want to save? It doesn't make sense to save after each cell edit.

Comment: Because I would like to write the new value to the same file I am reading from.

Comment: That's another issue. You will have to write back *all* current values to the file. But you probably don't want to do this each time a cell is changed. You'd better implement some kind of save button.

Comment: Ahh yeah thats probably be better! Thanks!